# How can I increase the map size in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, openstreetmap

I want to plot points in an openstreetmap. To determine a suitable range for the map I want to use `min()` and `max()` and increase the size by 10%:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
coords <- data.frame(cbind(c(-2.121821, -2.118570, -2.124278),
c(51.89437, 51.90330, 51.90469)))
topleft <- c(max(coords[,2]) + 0.1 * max(coords[,2]),
min(coords[,1]) - 0.1 * min(coords[,1]))
bottomright <- c(min(coords[,2]) - 0.1 * min(coords[,2]),
max(coords[,1]) + 0.1 * max(coords[,1]))

map <- openproj(openmap(topleft, bottomright, zoom = "16", type="osm"))
```

When I now try to create the map R eats up all my resources and I have to kill the process. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1     OpenStreetMap_0.3.1 rgdal_0.8-14        raster_2.2-12       sp_1.0-14          
[6] rJava_0.9-6
```

Comment: Why oh why no reproducible example?

Comment: Ok, I expanded my example. I hope this helps

Comment: Yup. That helped. You should be extending your map by 10% of the *range* of values, which is not the same thing as multiplying each of the coordinates themselves by 1.1 or 0.9, as your code in essence does.  To see the difference, think about what your code will do to a box one degree on a side centered at (0,0), vs one centered at (100000, 100000). See how the second one will get expanded by a lot more than the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extending the range incorrectly, as you'll see if you have a look at the computed values of `topleft` and `bottomright`.

A less error-prone approach might use the function `extendrange()` (which is used by many R plotting functions to add a little buffer around the most extreme points in the plot).

```
xx <- extendrange(coords[[1]], f=0.10)
yy <- extendrange(coords[[2]], f=0.10)
tl <- c(max(yy), min(xx))
br <- c(min(yy), max(xx))
map <- openproj(openmap(tl, br, zoom="16", type="osm"))
plot(map)
```

[image]

Comment: Yesterday night I was thinking about using the range between min and max value, too. But I did not know the extendrange function so far which seems even better.
I guess my map just got too big and the calculation consumed a lot of cpu power. Is this correct?

Comment: @mrub -- That's exactly what I think happened. You were asking it to load 10 **degrees** worth of latitudinal data, and it was just going to take a *very* long time to do that.